# Polling an AWS SQS queue for messages with certain attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have set up a standard queue with AWS SQS and I want to poll this `queue` for messages containing a
specific `attribute`, preferably using the `boto3` library in python. I know that `boto3` has a
method `recieve_message()` which polls messages from the queue. However, I want to only get those messages which contain a specific attribute. A naive approach is to iterate through the `receive_message()` output and check if a `message` in `receive_message()` contains the `attribute`, but I was wondering if there is another solution to this problem.

Comment: Who is publishing msg to sqs? Is that from your application too?

Comment: Yes, I have an EC2 pushing message to an SQS queue and I want to poll these messages from a lambda, but I only want those messages which contain a specific message attribute. The boto3 library has this function: [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message), does the MessageAttributeNames do this?

Comment: Could you send SNS and then SQS subscribe to SNS?

Comment: Basically I am enqueuing the completed jobs into the queue (or notification service) and from a lambda I want to check if a job is completed by polling for the job id. The ids are "unique" so I don't want to create separate queues for a job id. I was thinking of publishing a message with the job id as an attribute to SNS and having the lambda subscribe to that topic. But I don't know of an API call in SNS which does `topic.filterMessagesByAttribute(attribute)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't filter certain messages with SQS solely, however, you can do that with SNS.

You can publish the messages to an SNS topic. The message filter feature of SNS enables endpoints subscribed to an SNS topic to receive only the subset of topic messages it is interested in. So you can ensure only the relevant messages with specific attributes are enqueued to the consumer's queue.

Refer to [Filter Messages Published to Topics](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/filter-messages-published-to-topics/) and [SNS subscription filtering policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html).

Answer (score 0):

Selective polling is not supported in SQS `ReceiveMessage` API. An alternative is to let your EC2 send messages containing different attributes into different SQS queues.